# Why is it not possible to create an Azure Key vault key with ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

In the [documentation of ARM templates resources types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2018-02-14/vaults), there is no `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys` resource type.

This means that **it is not possible to create a key in an Azure key vault by using arm templates.**

I would like to know if this is actually intended for security reasons maybe, or just not supported yet.

I am experimenting with the new server side storage encryption with customer manager keys and I would like to create the following in a single template:

- Key vault
- Key in the key vault
- Disk encryption set

Comment: Presumably because the contents of a Key Vault are not Azure resources, any more than files in a Storage Account.

Comment: But @HongOoi, it is possible to create secrets via ARM templates why not keys?

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906355-azure-key-vault/suggestions/34256263-create-key-vault-keys-via-arm-template

Answer (score 1):

Because `create key` operation is not exposed with the [ARM Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/createkey/createkey). Only with the Key Vault Rest API. But ARM Templates only operate against ARM Rest Api.